# scheme- writing a foldl /fold-left like function that works on first 3 items of the given list

Tags: scheme, fold, chez-scheme

I would like to write a function that gets and infix expression and changes it to prefix.
at first let's assume we only deal with + operator, so I want to change the expression 1+1+1 into: (+ (+ 1 1) 1)

I want to do it using foldl or foldl-like matter:
taking the second item in the list (which is always the operand) appending it with the first and the third (in that order) then I would like the expression we've just appended to become the first item in the list so I would do the same on the rest of the list recursively.

Iv'e tried the following:

```
(lambda (lst)
       (fold-left (lambda (pmLst)
          `(,((cadr pmLst) ,(car pmLst) (caddr pmLst)) ,(cddr pmLst)))
                        '()
                        lst))
```

but then I realized that the lambda given to the fold-left has to have 2 arguments but I would like to deal with the first 3 items of the list.

I hope I've made myself clear cause it got a bit tricky..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `fold` wont do what you want. If you imagine the expression `(5 + 3 + 2)` then using a fold with `proc` as the procedure do this:

```
(proc 2 (proc '+ (proc 3 (proc '+ (proc 5 '())))))
```

A way would be to make a function that returns the odd and even elements in their own list so that `'(+ 2 - 3)` becomes `(+ -) and (2 3)` and then you could do it like this:

```
(define (infix->prefix expr)
  (if (pair? expr)
      (let-values ([(ops args) (split (cdr expr))])
        (fold (lambda (op arg acc)
                (list op acc (infix->prefix arg)))
              (car expr)
              ops
              args))
      expr))
```

However the size of both is much greater than just rolling your own recursion:

```
(define (infix->prefix expr)
    (define (aux lst acc)
      (if (pair? lst)
          (aux (cddr lst)
               (list (car lst)
                     acc
                     (infix->prefix (cadr lst))))
          acc))

    (if (pair? expr)
        (aux (cdr expr) (infix->prefix (car expr)))
        expr))

(infix->prefix '(1 + 2 - 3))
; ==> (- (+ 1 2) 3)
```

There is no operator precedence here. Everything is strictly left to right.